# Reduce 6 volts to 5 volts?

Tags: voltage, resistors, diodes

I want to install a Siriusxm radio receiver in an antique car with a 6 volt system. The Sirius receiver 12 volt power adaptor states that the output is 5 volts. If I wire the receiver directly into the 6 volt system, will that extra volt burn out the receiver over time? If so, what device can be wired in to drop the voltage to 5 volts? I have read here about diodes and SEPIC to do this, but not being savvy in electronics, I don't understand which way to go. Could someone advise me on how specifically to do this? Any recommendations on what I should buy, to include source if known, would be appreciated.

Comment: Automobile voltage is highly unstable. You would need to stabilize it even if it was 5V.

Comment: Use a low drop out voltage regulator. It's drop out should be 0.5V or lower if you can.

Comment: Thanks Passerby. The description of the LDO 7805 states "This regulator has a ~2V linear drop-out. That means you must give it at least 7V to get a clean 5V out". My car output is 6 volts (6.4). Is there another that will work?

Comment: @Opie 7805 is not an LDO

Comment: Proof that I don't know what I am doing! I really need some guidance when it comes to electronics.

Comment: Will this work?   https://www.pololu.com/product/2574

Comment: Sorry, need is the correct link.      https://www.pololu.com/product/2574.  Will this work?

Comment: I haven’t heard of the company, but if you believe their specs (no reason to assume otherwise), it looks like a good fit, and should support your 1.5 A.

Comment: The "6 volts" for your car system is a nominal value - the voltage will actually be a bit over 7 volts when the engine is running, and charging the battery.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to know, what current your device will draw.
I'd personally use a DC-DC with low voltage drop or a simple LDO if the current isn't too high. There's also an option, to use diodes.

option A: Buy over the internet or create your own low drop DC-DC buck converter, which will hold the power dissipation for current across your device.

[image]

option B: Use LM1117 5.0V if your current won't exceed 1A and you can have 6.3V on the input.

[image]

option C: Use 1N4007 and 1N4148 diodes in series (same direction), where the 1N4007 will cause ~0.7V drop and 1N4148 will cause ~0.3V drop.

[image]

option D: if the current is small, you can use just a simple voltage resistor with proper ratio!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jakey. The Sirius receiver requires 5 volts/1.5 Amps, so option B is out. You said "if the current isn't too high" for the other options. What options will work at 1.5 Amps?

Comment: Please define "isn't too high". Thanks.

Comment: The 1N4148 can only carry 50mA current. You need a power Schottky diode if you wanted 0.3V drop at ~1A. But two 1N4007 will also match here.

Comment: Keep in mind that the voltage drop of a Diode is dependent on the current flowing through it. Low currents will see less of a voltage drop. So make sure if you do this to add some capacitors and maybe a load resistor if your circuit uses little current. There are pretty straight forward graphs in diodes datasheets to show voltage drop vs. current.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest and cheapest way to drop a small amount of voltage would be too use a diode , there forward voltage drop is around 0.7v so is perfect for reducing small amounts of voltage, I hope this helps, also it shouldn’t burn out with the 1 extra volt there should be a 20% tolerance , but if your wanting to get it exact I would recommend using diodes. *EDIT* ( When using a diode remember to always check the data sheet for the voltage drop as this can vary)

Comment: This is a duplicate of part of @jakey's answer above.